# MacPorts-installed packages not working after updating to Lion

Tags: macos, macports

I recently upgraded OS X from 10.6 to 10.7. Since doing this, certain command line tools I installed via MacPorts, such as ImageMagick, stopped working. For example when I run `$ convert Jobs.png -resample 72 Jobs.png` I get:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenCL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libclparser.dylib
Referenced from: /opt/local/bin/convert
Reason: image not found
```

How can I fix this?

### What I've tried:

I've tried the following commands, to no avail:

```
$ sudo port selfupdate
$ sudo port upgrade outdated
$ sudo port upgrade imagemagick
```

The last gives:

```
--->  Activating perl5 @5.12.3_1+perl5_12
Error: Target org.macports.activate returned: Image error: /opt/local/share/man/man3p/App::Prove.3pm already exists and does not belong to a registered port.  Unable to activate port perl5. Use 'port -f activate perl5' to force the activation.
Error: Failed to install perl5
Log for perl5 is at: /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_lang_perl5/perl5/main.log
Error: The following dependencies were not installed: perl5
Error: Problem while installing glib2
To report a bug, see <http://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets>
```

Following the suggestion there I ran `$ sudo port -f activate perl5` but this yielded:

```
--->  The following versions of perl5 are currently installed:
--->      perl5 @5.8.9_0
--->      perl5 @5.12.3_1+perl5_12
Error: port activate failed: Registry error: Please specify the full version as recorded in the port registry.
```

At this point I'm at my wits' end, so any help is much appreciated!

Comment: What does /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_lang_perl5/perl5/main.log show as the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Their migration page](https://trac.macports.org/wiki/Migration) should cure all of your ills.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I had to run `sudo port -f activate perl5` after taking the steps there again, but this time it didn't yield the above errors, and after that ImageMagick installed fine.